# Redeclared 'button' defined above without usage

Tags: python, selenium, testing, pycharm

> **I try to automate testing of an Internet site in Pycharm. There is a warning in line 15: “Redeclared 'button' defined above without usage”.
>   What does it mean? (It is the same story with "choices")**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\TestFiles\chromedriver.exe')

locator = (By.ID, "guestname")
locator_css = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#guestname")
guest_input = driver.find_element(*locator)

guest_input.send_keys("Marcin Pilzak")

locator2 = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.MuiButton-containedPrimary")
button = driver.find_element(*locator2)

(LINE 15) button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.MuiButton-containedPrimary")

button.click()

locator2 = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "__button")
button = driver.find_element(*locator2)

button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("__button")
.
button.click()

choices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains('name') and contains(@class, '__input')]".sendKeys("UserName"))

choices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains('email') and contains(@class, '__input')]".sendKeys("Email"))

choices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains('phone') and contains(@class, '__input')]".sendKeys("Phone"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `button` twice!

What happens is that the python interpreter just uses the last declaration hence the warning:

> “Redeclared 'button' defined above without usage”

If you want to redeclare a variable you can but if you don't use it before redeclaring you will get that warning!

You should give a unique name for each variable!

The `choices` will not give you this warning because you use it for `send_keys`.

Yet you should change it to:

```
choices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(., 'name') and contains(@class, '__input')]").send_keys("UserName")

choices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(., 'email') and contains(@class, '__input')]").send_keys("Email")

choices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(., 'phone') and contains(@class, '__input')]").send_keys("Phone")
```

The `send_keys()` function needs to be out of the xpath...

Comment: Thanks, I deleted second button declaration. Now it works. By the way, does putting "choices.send_keys("UserName")" in new line (below choices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath......) make any difference?

Comment: @Virtual107 puting it in a new line shouldn't make a difference... the way you do it now is called chaining...